# Graphql Nestjs add arguments to type field

Tags: typescript, graphql, nestjs, prisma2

Hello how are you doing,
I have been learning Nestjs for the past week and enjoy it a lot.
I am currently using it with Prisma 2 to build a graphql server.
I want to add arguments in a graphql type field to be able to filter or
order the result using prisma.
to be clear, I want to be able to execute the following schema

```
query {
  findUniqueUser(where: { id: 1 }) {
    id
    email
    name
    posts(where: { title: { contains: "a" } }, orderBy: { createdAt: asc }, first: 10, skip: 5) {
      id
      title
      comments(where: { contain: { contains: "a" } }) {
        id
        contain
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the library [@paljs/plugins](https://paljs.com/plugins/select) to extract information from the GraphQLResolveInfo and make the query to prisma.
I am also using the library [prisma-nestjs-graphql](https://github.com/unlight/prisma-nestjs-graphql) to automatically generate all graphql type definitions.
Has anyone ever attempted that using nestjs?
Thank you and have a great day

Edit: I am using code-first graphql

Edit 2:
After digging around I found a way using `@ResolveField`.

```
@Query((returns) => Patient, { nullable: true, name: "patient" })
    async getPatient(@Args() params: FindUniquePatientArgs, @Info() info: GraphQLResolveInfo) {
        const select = new PrismaSelect(info).value;
        params = { ...params, ...select };
        return this.prismaService.patient.findUnique(params);
    }

    @ResolveField(() => File)
    async files(@Parent() patient: Patient, @Args() params: FindManyFileArgs) {
        return patient.files;
    }
```

I don't know if this is the best way of doing it so I leave the question unanswered for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will leave that here as the answer

```
    @Query((returns) => Patient, { nullable: true, name: "patient" })
    async getPatient(@Args() params: FindUniquePatientArgs, @Info() info: GraphQLResolveInfo) {
        const select = new PrismaSelect(info).value;
        params = { ...params, ...select };
        return this.prismaService.patient.findUnique(params);
    }

    @ResolveField(() => File)
    async files(@Parent() patient: Patient, @Args() params: FindManyFileArgs) {
        return patient.files;
    }
```